# object required error

Tags: reporting-services

Can anyone tell me the reason for this error message in report manager? My report works fine in tool. My second parameter is cascaded (derived from) to the first parameter.

When I run the report for first time it works, but when immediately change any other parameter and try to execute it gives me no data in the result and the web page shows this error:

> Line: 13
>
> Char: 692
>
> Error: Object Required
>
> Code: 0

Why do I receive this error?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Javascripts version of a NullReferenceException.  If that is the case, there are a *billion* different reasons why this could happen.

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you please give a sample  possible reason. i am kind of new to this . Thanks

Comment: I would guess that it is trying to call a function that does not exist, or trying to access a property of a null object.